# Completed 406 Not Acceptable in devise

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am integrating ios app with rails server. 
Here, I have implemented devise authentication.
when a new person is signing up from my app, I get the following error in my logs

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"sss@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"sss@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: Any of those help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362910/rails-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-for-json-devise-requests

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Devise responding to json by default has been removed from version 2.2, So add

```
respond_to :json
```

in your application controller or the specific controller where you would like to respond with json.

Answer (score 2):

To not allow `json` acceptance for all controllers, but only for devise add

```
config.to_prepare do
  DeviseController.respond_to :html, :json
end
```

only to `config/application.rb` as recommended here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2209