# Devise with Simple Token Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise, simple-authentication

i am using the following gem and devise now, since devise remove the support for token authentication.
https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

What i am missing here is that, I have all the configuration setup but when i hit `http://localhost:3000/user/sign_in.json` using the RestConsole Tester on Google.

I am getting the following error:

## ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /users/sign_in.json

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>     actionpack (4.0.2)
>
> ### lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb, line 163
>
> ```
>         def initialize(controller)
>           @controller = controller
>          end
>
>         def handle_unverified_request
>           raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>         end
>       end
>     end
>
>     protected
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST is failing a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token check. You can validate this is the case by **temporarily** removing `protect_from_forgery` from your `application_controller.rb` which should make this work.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362910/rails-warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-for-json-devise-requests) provides a solution for overriding that check on a specific controller, which should be safe for login requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

Authenticate:

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in \
  -d '{"user" : { "email" : "test@example.com", "password" : "password"}}' \
  -c cookie`

Show:

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -X GET http://localhost:3000/pages/1.xml \
  -b cookie`

That works for me.