# cURL X-CSRF Token Issue

Tags: php, curl, proxy, csrf

I have this PHP proxy using `cURL` (below). Whenever it gets a `POST` the header `X-CSRF` token is set to null. The `X-CSRF` token is the only difference in the `POST` header between using the proxy and not.

So I am wondering how to go about fixing it so that the `X-CSRF` token is set correctly as it would without using the proxy?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0');

$browserRequestHeaders = getallheaders();
$curlRequestHeaders = array();
foreach ($browserRequestHeaders as $name => $value) {
  $curlRequestHeaders[] = $name . ": " . $value;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlRequestHeaders);


switch ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
  case "POST":
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents("php://input"));
  break;
  case "PUT":
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen("php://input"));
  break;
}

//Other cURL options.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);

// Cookie cURL options.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

//handle other cookies cookies
foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v) {
  if(is_array($v)){
    $v = serialize($v);
  }
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"$k=$v; domain=.$cookiedomain ; path=/");
  }

// Set the request URL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Make the request.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Image showing headers https://i.stack.imgur.com/78fVV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to proxy the `$_SESSION` id between client and servers in `php`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using AJAX calls and as your picture shows, the `X-CSRF-Token` header does not get set on those calls. You need to set it explicitly as explained in [Adding X-CSRF-Token header globally to all instances of XMLHttpRequest();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196140/adding-x-csrf-token-header-globally-to-all-instances-of-xmlhttprequest), e.g. with (copied from there):

```
(function() {
var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
    token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
    this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    return send.apply(this, arguments);
};
}());
```

So the fix is not in PHP but in your AJAX calling code. Replace `token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');` with code that obtains the CSRF token from your HTML.

Comment: The $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'); also contains null.

Comment: yes, as suggested in the edit: you need to replace that with code that works on the actual HTML that you have; you'll need to look at the HTML source code that is returned from the website to find the right element for your use case

Comment: The meta element that normally contains the `CSRF` token is null in the html through the proxy. Normally it gets set when not using the proxy, but for some reason the `CSRF` does not get set. The `JS` you supplied would only return a value other than null if the post didn't return a null value.

`<meta id="csrf-token-meta-tag" name="csrf-token" content="">`
isn't turning into
`<meta id="csrf-token-meta-tag" name="csrf-token" content="asldkfh">`