# Elm: http.post csrf

Tags: csrf, elm

How can we get `http.post` to set `X-CSRFToken` header on the request?
The token should be taken from `csrftoken` cookie, which is set by the backend.
Do we need to use `http.send` for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code (https://github.com/evancz/elm-http/blob/3.0.1/src/Http.elm), `post` is hard-coded with
empty (i.e. `[]`) http header.
So if you want to have custom header, `post`
does not work, you'll have to use `send` instead.

Other solution you might want to consider is to
 enforce CSRF token for all http calls,
like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196317/1238847) stackoverflow answer suggests.