# How to automatically convert CSRF Tokens to HTTP request headers in Elm?

Tags: elm, django-csrf, csrf-token

I am writing a single page application in Elm to interface with a Django backend. The Django Rest Framework provides a CSRF token in a cookie but expects all requests to contain the token in an HTTP header.

Is there a way to declaratively instruct Elm to return the CSRF token as HTTP header with each request? E.g., along the line how I would configure it in JS/Axios:

```js
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
```

There is an [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39818433/4090111) that implies to manually extract the token from the cookie and then use `Http.send` for each request. That would mean to wrap all HTTP request functions by hand.

Comment: Not really sure what this question provides over the linked question?

Comment: The linked question has an answer that is five years old. A lot has changed in Elm-Land in the meantime, it seems. Therefore, I’m asking if a solution exists in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [version 2.0.0 of the elm/http library](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/2.0.0), you would need to use [`request`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/2.0.0/Http#request) in order to provide headers. It's fairly common for an application to use a customized version of these "base" methods that ask for whatever your environment requires.

```
get httpConfig route tagger decoder =
    Http.request
        { method = "GET"
        , headers = httpConfig.headers
        , url = httpConfig.baseUrl ++ route
        , body = Http.emptyBody
        , expect = Http.expectJson tagger decoder
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        }

post httpConfig route value tagger decoder =
    Http.request
        { method = "POST"
        , headers = httpConfig.headers
        , url = httpConfig.baseUrl ++ route
        , body = Http.stringBody "application/vnd.api+json" (Encode.encode 0 value)
        , expect = Http.expectJson tagger decoder
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Implicitly, I take your answer also to mean that there is no declarative way to instruct Elm to automatically return the CSRF token from a CSRF cookie as header field. I do indeed need to write additional code to first retrieve the cookie and then add a custom header for each request.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster yes

Comment: Right. Because of Elm's design, nothing happens "automatically", every function can only operate on its inputs (i.e. there is no such thing as global state).