# How to read cookies in Elm?

Tags: cookies, elm, elm-port

I've learned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70206619/4090111) that there currently is no simple way to turn cookie-based CSRF tokens into HTTP request headers in Elm. Thus, to write a single page application (SPA) that works nicely with a Django Rest Framework backend, I need to manually retrieve the CSRF-Token from the corresponding cookie value.

How do I retrieve a cookie value in Elm? Does Elm provide runtime support for this via some Command? Or do I need to retrieve the cookie using plain JavaScript and provide it to the ELM SPA via a port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Elm 0.9, you need to use [Ports](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/ports.html) to read the cookie from JavaScript and pass it back to the Elm application.

In my application, I do the following. I define a `fetchCsrfToken` port that I use from Elm to call a JavaScript function that reads the cookie. That function then triggers a callback to Elm via a `csrfTokenReciever` port. My Elm application subscribes to that event via subscriptions.

```
-- Ports.elm

port fetchCsrfToken : () -> Cmd msg
port csrfTokenReciever : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

```
-- Main.elm

init : Flags -> Url -> Key -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags url key =
  -- ...
  (model, Ports.fetchCsrfToken ())
  

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Ports.csrfTokenReciever GotCsrfToken
```

```
// index.js

app.ports.fetchCsrfToken.subscribe(function (str) {
  const value = getCookie('csrftoken')
  if (value === null) {
    app.ports.csrfTokenReciever.send('')
  } else {
    app.ports.csrfTokenReciever.send(value)
  }
})
```

Comment: To my understanding, I can use Ports to send data from Elm to JS, but I need a Subscription to funnel data from JS to Elm - or am I missing something? I can see two ways to do that: In JS, write a listener on cookie changes that sends data to an Elm subscription. Or write a JS function that gets triggered via an Elm Port, and which in turn writes data via a subscription back to Elm. Correct? Which one should I use?

Comment: @UlrichSchuster you're correct, you will also need to use the subscriptions. I follow the second method you described. I've extended my answer with an example code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Elm 0.19.1

### **First solution:**

Use of **2 ports, a subscription and some JS/TS code** like @viam0Zah mentioned.

---

### Second solution:

Pass the CSRF into your flags at init

```
    const app = Elm.Main.init({
      node: document.querySelector("main"),
      flags: {
        csrfToken: getCookie('csrftoken')
      }
    });
```

add csrfToken to Flags

```
type alias Flags =
    { ---
    , csrfToken : String
    }
```

And don't forget to add a decoder for the csrfToken:

```
import Json.Decode as D

flagsDecoder : D.Decoder Flags
flagsDecoder =
    D.succeed Flags
        |> ---
        |> D.required "csrfToken" D.string
```

---

If you want to be more robust and extend type safety for both solutions - flags and ports, you should check out https://elm-ts-interop.com/, it's just amazing!