# Upload pictures with TinyMCE and RoR on protected page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, tinymce-4

I don't need a concret solution, but someone that gives me a closer hint to solve my problem. I have an ruby on rails 4 intranet application, that is login protected. In this application I have an editing page, where I also use TinyMCE. It has the ability to give it an URL where to send the picture to for uploading it (see [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)).
I implemented the upload routine with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and it works great outside of TinyMCE. If it's possible I would also keep that plugin.
But as I said CarrierWave is currently not working with TinyMCE and an asynchronous upload.

So do you have an idea how I can upload an image, but with correct session token (asynchronously). And the picture URL that not saving the database, but in the text shown in TinyMCE. Is there a plugin that can help me or anything else?
If you need closer information please tell me.

Best regards
Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [image plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/) for TinyMCE and set `file_picker` properties and callbacks, so you can attach files from client-side, rather than URL.

```
tinymce.init({
    // Include image plugin on plugin list
    plugins: [ 'image'],
    // Include image button on toolbar
    toolbar: ['image'],
    // Enable title field in the Image dialog
    image_title: true, 
    // Enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
    automatic_uploads: true,
    // URL of your upload handler
    // (YOU SHOULD MAKE AN ENDPOINT TO RECEIVE THIS AND RETURN A JSON CONTAINING: {location: remote_image_url})
    images_upload_url: '/text_images',
    // Here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
    file_picker_types: 'image', 
    // And here's your custom image picker
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

      input.onchange = function() {
        var file = this.files[0];

        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // Call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };

      input.click();
    }
});
```

Add `text_images` to your `route.rb` file:

```
  match "text_images" => "text_images#create", via: :post
```

And create your proccessing action like this:

```
  def create
    if params[:file].class == ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
        @image = Picture.new(image: params[:file])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @image.save
            format.json { render json: { "location": @image.image.url }.to_json, status: :ok }
          else
            format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

This is a very crude implementation, you should make it more secure for your application context, validating and filtering large or invalid files!

UPDATE: There was a recent upgrade on the syntax for new versions of TinyMCE for the `onchange` function to include a result reader attribute on the create method of the `blobCache` object:

```
      input.onchange = function() {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = function () {
        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, reader.result);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so far for that detailed answer. I'll try it out and mark your answer as correct, when it's working :)

Comment: Ok your answer got me further, but didn't solve the problem, that I had a CSRF-warning, when uploading the picture. I had to write my custom images_upload_handler function. This way I could add the csrf_token that RoR generates. Now the application doesn't throw the warning anymore and kills the session.
I will write my final solution at the weekend.

Comment: You should make your life easier, never run into those problems again http://stackoverflow.com/a/24196317/3399504

Comment: Great thanks for that idea! Now I have a slim and easy working solution.

Comment: This works but if you are using paperclip for `Picture` then you will need to ignore file type validation as well as `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` on the api endpoint for uploading.